# Is 戈 a joyo kanji? What does it mean?

Tags: kanji, jōyō-kanji

I'm taking a look by recommendation to the "remembering the kanji" book. In it appears the kanji below. I look for it in a list of joyo kanji and it doesnt appear, at least not when I look for it by its meaning. The meaning the book says it has is "fiesta". Fiesta is a spanish word, and I dont even understand what it is doing in an english book unless it means something different in another language or japanese? Anyway, I'd like to know if this is a joyo kanji, and if this is the meaning it has "fiesta" and if that meaning it's the same meaning than the word "fiesta" in spanish

By the way, I can't type the kanji in my computer, so if anyone can add it to the title it's appreciated. Same thing happened with other couple of topics I've opened, and I realize since the topic title isnt descriptive, the topic isnt helpful for others

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This glyph is both a radical, and an independent character: [戈](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%88%88).  This has the *on'yomi* of **ka**, and the *kun'yomi* of **hoko**.  The independent character isn't used much in either Japanese or Chinese.  The original meaning was *"a dagger-axe, a polearm similar to a halberd"*.  In modern Chinese, it appears most often in names.  In modern Japanese, it's a less-common alternative spelling of 矛{ほこ}.

This is not included in the 常用漢字 list.